# Rails Server Won't Start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to start my rails server with "rails server".  I am getting the following error.

Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

when I use gems, it say it is updated.  Am I missing some type of path?

I am using MAC OSX Lion with the newest version of Ruby, Rake, Rails.

Comment: Add more info about your environment (what version of rails are you trying to run, are you using RVM and co, and so on...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `bundle install` to make sure all the bundled gems are installed and available to the project.

Then try starting the server with `bundle exec rails server` - it's possible you've got the rake gem installed at the system level at a slightly different version level than what rails want. If you run rails via `bundle exec`, it'll set everything up for you

Comment: Bundle Install worked, but I do I need the "rails" folder in my site's folder?